# JBoss Error: Could not load class designated by HandlesTypes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I am getting these weird JBoss errors while deploying the war file.

`INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS018227: Could not load class designated by HandlesTypes [com.companyName.ClassName].: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com..companyName.ClassName from [Module "deployment.projectName.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]`

These look information error but it is causing further issues in the deployment.
Using `JBoss EAD 6.1`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have your .class (compiled file) into your .war -> classes (directory).

In my case, I had a class implementing WebApplicationInitializer interface (Spring interface) and Wildfly 8.2 couldn't load it... it needs to have .class file into /WEB-INF/classes folder...

I solved my problem moving my file to my web app module (.war) because the bug is solved in Wildfly 9 only at this moment.
see: [enter link description here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4205)